# Installing petergate returns error `Could not find generator 'petergate:install'`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-generate, rails-generators

I keep getting this error. The full text is as follows:

```
$ rails g petergate:install
Running via Spring preloader in process 96515
Could not find generator 'petergate:install'. Maybe you meant 'devise:install', 'responders:install' or 'integration_test'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

I've already run `bundle install`. The gem is installed and within my gem directory. I know it shouldn't make a difference, but Devise is installed and my user model is called `user.rb`.

Oddly enough, when I try and replicate the problem, by creating a new app and installing devise then petergate, the generation works.

I've tried uninstalling petergate, taking it out of my bundle and putting it back in again, every combination of `bundle`/`bundle install`/`bundle update`, moving it to the top of the gemfile, trying `rails generate` rather than `rails g` , rebooting my computer, but nothing seems to be working.

My `Gemfile` is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.5'
gem 'petergate', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'pry-byebug'
end
group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.4', '>= 4.4.2'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0'
```

`Gemfile.lock`:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.1.6)
      actionpack (= 5.1.6)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.1.6)
      actionpack (= 5.1.6)
      actionview (= 5.1.6)
      activejob (= 5.1.6)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.1.6)
      actionview (= 5.1.6)
      activesupport (= 5.1.6)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.1.6)
      activesupport (= 5.1.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.1.6)
      activesupport (= 5.1.6)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.1.6)
      activesupport (= 5.1.6)
    activerecord (5.1.6)
      activemodel (= 5.1.6)
      activesupport (= 5.1.6)
      arel (~> 8.0)
    activesupport (5.1.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (8.0.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (8.2.0)
      execjs
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    bindex (0.5.0)
    bootstrap (4.0.0)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 6.0.3)
      popper_js (>= 1.12.9, < 2)
      sass (>= 3.5.2)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (10.0.2)
    coderay (1.1.2)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    crass (1.0.3)
    devise (4.4.3)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 6.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubi (1.7.1)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.9.23)
    friendly_id (5.1.0)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.0.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.3.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.2.2)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    method_source (0.9.0)
    mini_mime (1.0.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    nio4r (2.3.0)
    nokogiri (1.8.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    petergate (1.8.1)
      activerecord (> 4.0.0)
    pg (1.0.0)
    popper_js (1.12.9)
    pry (0.11.3)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.9.0)
    pry-byebug (3.6.0)
      byebug (~> 10.0)
      pry (~> 0.10)
    puma (3.11.3)
    rack (2.0.4)
    rack-test (1.0.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.1.6)
      actioncable (= 5.1.6)
      actionmailer (= 5.1.6)
      actionpack (= 5.1.6)
      actionview (= 5.1.6)
      activejob (= 5.1.6)
      activemodel (= 5.1.6)
      activerecord (= 5.1.6)
      activesupport (= 5.1.6)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.1.6)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    railties (5.1.6)
      actionpack (= 5.1.6)
      activesupport (= 5.1.6)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    responders (2.4.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    sass (3.5.6)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    turbolinks (5.1.0)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.1)
    turbolinks-source (5.1.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.1.8)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    warden (1.2.7)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (3.5.1)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.6.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootstrap (~> 4.0.0)
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  devise (~> 4.4, >= 4.4.2)
  friendly_id (~> 5.1.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  jquery-rails
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  petergate (~> 1.8, >= 1.8.1)
  pg (>= 0.18, < 2.0)
  pry-byebug
  puma (~> 3.7)
  rails (~> 5.1.5)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.1
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what this could be? I'm tearing my hair out.

Comment: install devise and run migration then install petergate .

Comment: @Mezbah Yes, that works on a fresh app. However, devise is already installed and migrated (the user model was generated by devise). I've spent too much time on this app to delete everything and start over.

Comment: `bundle exec rails g petergate:install`?

Comment: @TomLord Tried that too, and `bundle exec rails generate petergate:install` unfortunately. However, I think I've now found a solution, which I posted below. Thanks very much for the help though, I've given you an upvote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I sort of ended up solving this, here's how. It's a very very hacky solution, but when all else fails...

Since it was working on a fresh, new app, I made a commit to this new app before running petergate:install and after. I then pushed up to github and compared the two.

The changes are actually very simple - a small migration, a bit of text added to your `User.rb` model. So I did the same things. And hey presto, it's now working, and interactions with the gem are too, so I'm not sure what the problem was.

On a more complicated gem where you're likely to need other command-line functionality in the future, or where install makes a ton of changes, this is more likely to be an issue, but on a simple gem like this, it's seemed to work okay.

Hope this helps anyone having the same (or a similar) problem.

Comment: What was the "bit of text"?